# Background image not covering whole screen

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have recently been creating a link in-bio page and I am trying to make the background image cover the whole screen but it is only covering parts of the screen where I have objects like a header or list. Below I have the CSS code that I used to insert the background image.

```
body {
background: url(./942775.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your `body` element is not the full size of your viewport. Try stretching `html` and `body` to the full window:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/296150main_2-226.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
main {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>Hello world</main>
```